# I really don't understand the answer to my question; what can I do?

Tags: support

I've got a few question on calculating the number of elements of an order in a group (see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/266752/number-of-elements-of-given-order-in-a-group) and [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/266524)). This goes from either calculating all the elements of all the types of orders to calculating the number of elements of say order 20. I'm not sure what to do know because **I asked a question on it and I didn't understand the answer** so I tried asking for an explanation on the comments bit but I've had no responses and I know your not supposed to duplicate questions, or ask very similar questions.

What could I do now?

Comment: I am going to move this to the main site. Please ask math questions there!

Comment: I think that despite the title, this is actually a question about how to use the main site, not a mathematical question.

Comment: I made some edits to emphasise why this question is suitable for meta (please fix if I've made a mistake).  Voted to reopen.

Comment: One option is to put a bounty on the question, 50 points should be enough. Choose the formulation "the given answers do not contain enough detail", and add a remark indicating which part of the answer should be explained in more detail.